# Registering generic types in Windsor container

Tags: c#, generics, castle-windsor

I need to register open generic of a type in my Windsor Container. How does this thing works?

`container.Register(Component.For<IRepository<??>>().UsingFactoryMethod(x => x.Resolve<IDataContext>().GetRepository<??>()));`

Basically, I want to register IRepository as open generic and then create the repository from the IDataContext based on the passed generic type. Is this supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When registering open generic use non-generic method:

```
Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>))...
```

When resolving via `UsingFactoryMethod` you can have access to the type that is requested, so you can pass the type to your `GetRepository` and resolve the repository based on the type (System.Type object) you pass.

As a sidenote I must say I find your design rather unusual. It's more common that a repository holds a reference to data context, not the other way around. Perhaps you'd want to take another look at the design instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I know about the design, the problem is I'm working with a legacy API which things seemingly are the other way around!

Comment: well then I'm afraid unless you have a non-generic overload of `GetRepository` you're in for `methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod().Invoke()`